# How to design Validator class in regards to SRP?

Tags: php, solid-principles, single-responsibility-principle

Is it better to have a validator class which have methods such as validateUrl(), validateEmail(), validateInt(), etc ?
Or, URLValidator class, EmailValidator class, and INTValidator class ?

Comment: I would say this primarily opinion based. I think you should make something that is the easiest or most logic for you

Comment: @SuperDJ Opinion based ? I just want to know the design by SRP principle. If you say so, is responsibility opinion-based ? Anyway, which one do you prefer ?

Comment: I made 1 class to do all the validating just to keep the classes folder a bit cleaner. But as every programmer has its own prevered style, I can't say that either way is right or wrong

Comment: You should understand what are SOLID principles here for -> to keep your code clean, easily understandable, readable, maintainable. Having a validator class seems very important to me since your have many fields to check, so you can start by doing so, if afterwards you notice that this class is too big and need to be split up because some fields need real complicate vérifications, go for it!!

Comment: @SuperDJ Thanks for your comment. But, let me ask you one more question hehehe... Do you prefer the class to have static method or not ? I think using static method is bad, but validating arguments in a function is very often to do. So, I think it's better to have static method than instantiating or injecting the validator class to almost all classes. What's your opinion ?

Comment: @smarber Do you prefer the validator class use static methods or not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst I agree that this is primarily opinion based I think that you should have a single class per validator. Otherwise what is the single responsibility of your class? To do all the validation? As suggested you could start out with a `Validator` that did everything and move towards separate classes later or your validator could just be a facade for all validation with the specific validation in separate classes.

As for the static question, that will likely depend on you need to stub those validators in your tests. In which case having them static will be a pain.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to split the common validation logic (`Validator` class) and concrete validation logic (`ValidationRule` class and its descendants). This is the case in Symfony framework.

The way to build most actively used validation rules into `Validator` class is used in Laravel framework, but I really don't like it because it violates SRP and makes `Validator` class bloated with unrelated logic.